# Cannot load custom view from nib into another view made programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, uiview

Looking at some of the other questions, this is the code I implemented in the .m of the view implementing the custom keyboard.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
if (self) {

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [self addGestureRecognizer:
     [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                             action:@selector(becomeFirstResponder)]];


   NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FormulaKeyboard" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id object in bundle) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[FormulaKeyboard class]])
            keyboard = (FormulaKeyboard *)object;
    }   


    self.inputView = keyboard;





}
return self;
```

}

Below is the error that showed up.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'

When I load the nib in an actual view controller, it works fine. However, as evidenced above, it doesn't work when I try loading it inside another view.

Also, in the nib, I set the file owner's class to UIViewController and attached it to the main view, since this was what another SO question instructed. I'm not sure if I need to modify this since I'm adding the custom view inside another view and not a viewc controller.

Thanks

EDIT:

.h of view implementing keyboard

```
@interface EquationTextField : UIView <KeyInput> {

FormulaKeyboard *keyboard;

}

@property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputView;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `xib` if you `ctrl` + `click` the `File's Owner` you will most likely see that you have a `view` outlet that is connected to the top level `view` object in the `xib`.

[image]

1. Refers to an `IBOutlet` in your code
2. Refers to an object in Interface Builder

The reason this works inside a `UIViewController` is that a `UIViewController` has a property `view` which gets connected up when loading the `xib`.

A `UIView` subclass does not normally have a property called `view` therefore you get an exception.

Seems as you are grabbing the item from the top level objects array returned by the `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` method you do not need this connection in the `xib`. Therefore you can disconnect this connection in the `xib` file.

**Alternatively**

You could:

- Change the `File's Owner` class to the class of your custom view.
- Make `inputView` an `IBOutlet`
- Connect `inputView` to your custom keyboard in the `xib`
- Then just use

  ```
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FormulaKeyboard" owner:self options:nil];
  ```

Comment: I deleted the connection in the xib. It runs fine now, but they keyboard doesn't show up when I click the view. I've added the code that should bring up the keyboard to the question. Thanks

Comment: I've tried adding different views as the inputView and even getting rid of the inputView property, but the keyboard hasn't shown up at all.

Comment: If this `self.inputView = keyboard;` is the code that should bring up the keyboard, it does not do what you think. This is simply assigning `keyboard` to an ivar called `inputView`, you need to also add it to the view hierarchy e.g. `[self addSubview:keyboard];`

Comment: Have you made sure that `nil != keyboard`?

Comment: Is the code you posted the same as the code you have? Where is `keyboard` even declared?

Comment: I had a pointer to it in the header. I added it to the code in the original question

Comment: I got it to work by going into the nib and changing the keyboard's class from UIView to FormulaKeyboard. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your view does not have a property called 'inputView', hence when you set the property on self, you get the exception.